# Citing vital records using tufte-book & natbib

Tags: natbib, tufte

I'm using the `tufte-book` class to help my mom write a family history. I'm running into a problem with figuring out how to cite vital records such as birth certificates, marriage documents, microfilms, etc. Most of them have no years or authors, and the text is so long that the margin is too full of text. (In fact, I get a "Too many unprocessed floats" error.)

Here's an example:

> Baptismal Record for Thomas Brady, 29 March 1860, Killakeen,
>   Drumlumman Parish, County Cavan; Microfilm #1279229 Parochial
>   Registers of Drumlumman South and Ballymachugh, 1837 - 1935; Family
>   History Library, Loudonville, NY.

What I would like to do is be able to just cite a bit in the sidebar (ex: Baptismal Record for Thomas Brady) and then have the full text in the bibliography at the end of the book. I would also like to suppress the year for things that just don't have years.

**Edit**
Here is what I have done to pretty much solve the problem:

Use bibtex instead, with `authortitle` style selected.

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,openright]{tufte-book}
%Resolve bibhang error problem
\usepackage{natbib}
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax

%authortitle shows only the author and shorttitle or shorthand
\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
  autocite=footnote,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

Here, for example, is the `biblio.bib` entry:

```
@manual{baptismthomasbrady2,
shorthand = {Baptismal Record for Thomas Brady, 29 March 1860},
note = {Baptismal Record for Thomas Brady, 29 March 1860, Killakeen, Drumlumman Parish, County Cavan; Microfilm \#1279229 Parochial Registers of Drumlumman South and Ballymachugh, 1837 - 1935; Family History Library, Loudonville, NY.},
}
```

So now my text looks like (only shows `shorthand`):
[image: Autocite in text]

And the bibliography looks like (only shows `note`):
[image: Bibliography]

Comment: An example of code is necessary.

Comment: @egreg, What exact code would you like me to cite? The .bib file? The citation in the text of the .tex file?

Comment: Well, how can we guess how you write the document?

Comment: @egreg, I'm still confused. I wrote it like a normal tex document, with the \cite{} command. What would be useful for you to see, in order to help answer my question?

Comment: The edit solved your problem? Why don't you add it as an answer instead? As it is, it's unclear what you're asking: I don't see the point in loading natbib and biblatex, for instance. I would suggest enriching your bib entry with more fields, perhaps using a `@misc` entry type (or maybe `@manuscript` from the [biblatex-manuscripts](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-manuscripts) style/package).